# Check if ASP Label is visible on different page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

The current code I am working on is a mess. Currently, I have an aspx page that has some javascript and sets a tooltip for various asp:buttons that are on an ascx page (not the current aspx). It looks like this:

```
function setTooltips() {
$("[id*='btnSave']").mousemove(function (ev) { ButtonToolTip(ev, this, "Click to save"); });
$("[id*='btnClear']").mousemove(function (ev) { ButtonToolTip(ev, this, "Clear fields"); });
// more button tooltips set.
}
```

In the ascx page, I also have an asp:label. I'm creating a javascript method to display an alert based on the visibility of this label. I'm having trouble finding the control and its visibility.

Here is what the asp label code looks like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnl_alert" UpdateMode="Always">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_alert" runat="server" Text="There are several issues found.<br /><br />" Visible="false" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Is there a way to check the visibility of the asp label so that I can implement the function I just wrote for the alert?

I have tried:

```
if (document.getElementById('lbl_alert').style.visibility == "visible")
```

but I am getting DOM exception - failed to execute.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> have an aspx page that has some javascript and sets a tooltip for various asp:buttons that are on an ascx page (not the current aspx).

Well, not quite!!! Context here matters.

Any "user" control built and dropped into any page?

the markup, the controls, and javascript and whatever else that ascx control has? It is placed in your existing aspx page. So, no, the controls are NOT in some other page.

better to state you have a user control dropped into a existing page, and, thus I want to select/use/enjoy/hide/show or do whatever with some of the buttons that the user control has.

Like all pages, most controls will often receive the current page class, or namespace as a prefix. And keep in mind, what happens if you drag that user control 2 or 4 times into the existing page? Then what do the buttons "id" become? I mean, the buttons can't have the same id, and yet it's perfect legal to drop in the user control multiple times, and each time, it will pull into the current page that markup.

So, say a super simple user control (ascx) is like this:

[image]

code behind for this UC (button click)

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Me.Label1.Text =
    $"control id = {Me.ClientID} <br/>
    Button ID = {Button1.ClientID} <br/>
    LableID = {Label1.ClientID}"

End Sub
```

Ok, so now lets create a new blank page, and drag + drop in the above.

We now have this:

```
<uc1:UserButton runat="server" id="UserButton" />
<br />
<br />
<uc1:UserButton runat="server" id="UserButton1" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="JavaScript - get Label 1"
    OnClientClick="gettest();return false"               
    />

<script>
    function gettest() {

        // var sLbl = '<%=UserButton.ClientID + "_Label1" %>'
        var sLbl = 'UserButton_Label1'

        var lbl1 = document.getElementById(sLbl)

        sResult = "Value of label1 in control is \n" + lbl1.innerText

        alert(sResult)

    }

</script>
```

So, since I dropped in the UC two times?

then how do the lables, and buttons get seperated out?

Simple:

The controls "inside" each control are prefixed with the "id"  you give the user control, and THEN a "_" and THEN the control inside.

So, note close the js code I used:

```
// var sLbl = '<%=UserButton.ClientID + "_Label1" %>'
var sLbl = 'UserButton_Label1'

var lbl1 = document.getElementById(sLbl)

sResult = "Value of label1 in control is \n" + lbl1.innerText

alert(sResult)
```

So, when I run the above, I thus get this:

[image]

So you need to prefix the control you want inside of the ascx page with the "id" of the control name used in the CURRENT page!

That's why I stated context matters here. the ASCX page does NOT matter, what matters is the name of the "UC" control used on the current page, since WHEN such controls are dragged + dropped into a existing page, then the controls for that UC control are prefixed with the "id" of the user control.

So, to be clear:

The controls are NOT in the other page, and that's really only a consdieration and view during design time.

At run time, those ascx controls are pulled + injected + rendered in the CURRENT page. Hence you can/have to prefix the controls in that ascx page with the "id" of the UC control used when "dropping" that control into any web page you like.

User controls are fantastic, since they represent re-usable controls, but at the end of the day, such controls are rendered in the current page.

Comment: Thank you!!! And I was not sure how to initially describe it. This is a huge help.